# Created an automated testing framework that runs using Firefox. Getting some errors back when I run the tests even though all the tests run fine

Tags: selenium, firefox, automation, cucumber, geckodriver

The framework is created using - 
Selenium - 3.8.0
Firefox - 64.0
Geckodriver - 0.23.0

The tests all run as expected but I am getting this back in the error log -

```
1545383503138   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/var/folders/l7/y0f9_v_s0zn05g1dbg_6_cvm0000gp/T/rust_mozprofile.gsKoM2BLZzKG"
1545383503659   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: resource://pdf.js/
1545383503659   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: about:reader*
1545383503756   addons.xpi-utils    WARN    addMetadata: Add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} is invalid: Error: Non-restartless extensions no longer supported(resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIInstall.jsm:647:13) JS Stack trace: loadManifestFromRDF@XPIInstall.jsm:647:13
loadFromRDF@XPIInstall.jsm:787:23
awaitPromise@XPIProvider.jsm:190:3
syncLoadManifestFromFile@XPIInstall.jsm:871:10
addMetadata@XPIDatabase.jsm:2417:21
processFileChanges@XPIDatabase.jsm:2769:21
checkForChanges@XPIProvider.jsm:2556:34
startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2134:25
callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:203:12
_startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:651:5
startup@AddonManager.jsm:804:9
startup@AddonManager.jsm:2774:5
observe@addonManager.js:66:9
1545383503756   addons.xpi-utils    WARN    Could not uninstall invalid item from locked install location
Can't find symbol 'GetGraphicsResetStatus'.
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm, line 2600: TypeError: addon is null
1545383505010   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 51345
1545383505105   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Dec 21, 2018 9:11:45 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

Can anyone tell me what might be causing this to show?

Answer (score 0):

This messages are coming from firefox itself, as you can see they have level of 'warn'.

In programming, warn == ignore :)